# Sound volume resets after reboot

Tags: sound

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 (computer previously had 18.04, tried doing an upgrade to 19.04 from that but it had some weird issues. The 19.04 install I have now was installed from a usb disk).

Everytime I restart the computer the volume gets set to 50% - which is way to loud for the headphones I have plugged in. The volume doesn't get reset immediately after restart. It'll be normal for about 30 seconds to a minute then it'll switch to 50%.

I've tried adding the below command to both my .profile and in startup applications. Neither of which stopped it from getting set to 50%.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 20%
```

driver and hardware information below. I have my headphones plugged into card 0, ALC1150 analog (I think. its plugged into the motherboard rca port in the back)

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Radeon R9 285/380 HDMI Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at dfe60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 1):

I reverted back to 18.04LTS which fixed this issue.
not sure why 19.04 did, but it had some other weird issues as well on my computer.